# Cannot Open Jupyter Notebook from Command Prompt on Windows

Tags: python, encoding, jupyter, charmap

I was using jupyter notebook just fine yesterday, but today when I went to open Jupyter Notebook from the command prompt by opening the command prompt from the folder where python is installed, it gives the error

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1322: character maps to ".

I have read elsewhere that this is because of an encoding problem. How do I fix this?

Didn't try anything other than restarting every once in a while. Don't know what to do.

Comment: try to uninstall and reinstall. you can do that via pip: `pip uninstall jupyter` and then `pip install jupyter`. If this doesn't work try to add this before launching command: `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share your `cmd` command as well as *full traceback*. Copy the actual text from open `cmd` window, paste it into the question, then format it as code.